# Using pfg plots to plot unit simplex in 3 dimensions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot something that looks a little like this:
[image]

I am using the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid=major]
\addplot3[
    surf,
] 
coordinates {
(1,0,0) 

(0,1,0) 

(0,0,1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but not quite getting the desired result, any hints on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Edited Version: Inserts Axes Ticks

The positioning of the ticks' label is a little "brittle": you could have ugly results depending on the values you set in the `\tdplotsetmaincoords` macro. Moreover, the code gets more and more complicated, so for even more complex figures it could be better to use `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \def\laxis{5}
  \def\ltriangle{3}
  \def\ltick{.2}
  %%% axes
  \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (\laxis,0,0) node [below] {$x$};
  \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,\laxis,0) node [right] {$y$};
  \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\laxis) node [left] {$z$};
  %%% axes ticks
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nticks}{floor(\laxis)-1}
  \begin{scope}[
    help lines,
    every node/.style={inner sep=1pt,text=black}
    ]
    \foreach \coord in {1,...,\nticks} {
      \draw (\coord,\ltick,0) -- ++(0,-\ltick,0) -- ++(0,0,\ltick)
      node [pos=1,left] {\coord};
      \draw (\ltick,\coord,0) -- ++(-\ltick,0,0) -- ++(0,0,\ltick)
      node [pos=1,right] {\coord};
      \draw (\ltick,0,\coord) -- ++(-\ltick,0,0) -- ++(0,\ltick,0)
      node [at start,above right] {\coord};
    }
  \end{scope}
  %%% figure
  \filldraw [opacity=.33,red] (\ltriangle,0,0) -- (0,\ltriangle,0)
  -- (0,0,\ltriangle) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### First Version

If you just want something similar to what you have posted, you could use the `tikz-3dplot` package.

The macro `\tdplotsetmaincoords{<angle1>}{<angle2>}` lets you choose the "point of view" for your figure (thinker a little with the values of the angles to get the desired result.)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \def\laxis{5}
  \def\ltriangle{3}
  \begin{scope}[->,red]
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (\laxis,0,0) node [below] {\textcolor{blue}{$x$}};
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,\laxis,0) node [right] {\textcolor{blue}{$y$}};
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\laxis) node [left] {\textcolor{blue}{$z$}};
  \end{scope}
  \filldraw [opacity=.5,green] (\ltriangle,0,0) -- (0,\ltriangle,0) --
  (0,0,\ltriangle) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there any way to have the coordinates on the axis?

Comment: @dimebucker91: Edited to add the ticks on the axes.

Comment: I cant get this code to work, i think the issue is with the scope section, any ideas why this wont compile for me?

Comment: @dimebucker91: Do you have the latest version of Ti*k*Z (3.0.0)?

Comment: I've updated now but still not working for some reason, i'll keep trying, thanks for your solution!

Comment: @dimebucker91 There was an error in the code which I've just corrected. `start` needs replacing with `at start`.

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it: use `patch` instead of `surf`. Both are the same, but the input format differs: `patch` accepts individual patch segments (triangles per default) whereas `surf` expects a matrix on input.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid=major]
\addplot3[
    patch,
] 
coordinates {
(1,0,0) 
(0,1,0) 
(0,0,1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or, with all faces:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid=major]
\addplot3[
    patch,
] 
coordinates {
% diagonal:
(1,0,0) 
(0,1,0) 
(0,0,1)

% bottom:
(0,0,0) 
(0,1,0) 
(1,0,0)

% side 1
(0,0,0) 
(0,0,1) 
(1,0,0)

% side 2
(0,0,0) 
(0,0,1) 
(0,1,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The colors are determined according to the Z coordinate, see the manual for how to adopt the colors.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way of changing the graph to have the same angle as what i drew?

Comment: To some extend, yes: consider modifying `view/h=<angle>` to your needs (triangle and error, I guess).

Comment: Note that `pgfplots` draws `z` upwards in every standard view, and it is recommended to keep it this way. You can, of course, simply exchange axis labels or exchange coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to some of us so here is another way to draw the simplex in three dimension,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=0.75*\textwidth,
                axis lines=middle,
                axis equal,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                xmin=0,
                xmax=1.25,
                ymin=0,
                ymax=1.25,
                zmin=0,
                zmax=1.25,
                xtick={0,1},
                ytick={0,1},
                ztick={0,1},
                view={135}{30}]
\addplot3[patch, color=blue!25, fill opacity=0.25, faceted color=black, line width=0.5pt] coordinates{(1,0,0) (0,1,0) (0,0,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea was to be able to tune the outer line colour, as well as the fill colour and opacity in order to see the axis crossing though the simplex.

Romain