# I do not know the key '/tikz/start'

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I am receiving an error message: `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/start' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. }`when I would like to draw a simplex-type graph.  I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering  
    \caption{Bla bla}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{115}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \def\laxis{7}
    \def\xtriangle{3}
    \def\ytriangle{4}
    \def\ztriangle{5}
    \def\ltick{.2}
    %%% axes
    \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (\laxis,0,0) node [below] {July 15};
    \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,\laxis,0) node [right] {July 29};
    \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\laxis) node [left] {August 12};
    %%% axes ticks
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nticks}{floor(\laxis)-1}
    \begin{scope}[
    help lines,
    every node/.style={inner sep=1pt,text=black}
    ]
    \foreach \coord in {1,...,\nticks} {
        \draw (\coord,\ltick,0) -- ++(0,-\ltick,0) -- ++(0,0,\ltick)
        node [pos=1,left] {\coord};
        \draw (\ltick,\coord,0) -- ++(-\ltick,0,0) -- ++(0,0,\ltick)
        node [pos=1,right] {\coord};
        \draw (\ltick,0,\coord) -- ++(-\ltick,0,0) -- ++(0,\ltick,0)
        node [start,above right] {\coord};
    }
    \end{scope}
    %%% figure
    \filldraw [opacity=.33,red] (\xtriangle,0,0) -- (0,\ytriangle,0)
    -- (0,0,\ztriangle) -- cycle;
    \def\x2triangle{6}
    \def\y2triangle{5}
    \def\z2triangle{2}
    \def\ltick{.2}
    \begin{scope}[
    help lines,
    every node/.style={inner sep=1pt,text=black}
    ]
    \foreach \coord in {1,...,\nticks} {
        \draw (\coord,\ltick,0) -- ++(0,-\ltick,0) -- ++(0,0,\ltick)
        node [pos=1,left] {\coord};
        \draw (\ltick,\coord,0) -- ++(-\ltick,0,0) -- ++(0,0,\ltick)
        node [pos=1,right] {\coord};
        \draw (\ltick,0,\coord) -- ++(-\ltick,0,0) -- ++(0,\ltick,0)
        node [start,above right] {\coord};
    }
    \end{scope}
    %%% figure
    \filldraw [opacity=.33,green] (\x2triangle,0,0) -- (0,\y2triangle,0)
    -- (0,0,\z2triangle) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:bla bla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no `start` style defined. Where did you find this code? How do you want to look a `start` node?

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks for the comments.  I found the code here: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251264/using-pfg-plots-to-plot-unit-simplex-in-3-dimensions]. I did some modification, i.e. I added another surface. I dont know though what you mean by your second question

Comment: Try `at start` in place of `start`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `at start` rather than `start`:

[image: double simplex]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{115}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \def\laxis{7}
  \def\xtriangle{3}
  \def\ytriangle{4}
  \def\ztriangle{5}
  \def\ltick{.2}
  %%% axes
  \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (\laxis,0,0) node [below] {July 15};
  \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,\laxis,0) node [right] {July 29};
  \draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\laxis) node [left] {August 12};
  %%% axes ticks
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nticks}{floor(\laxis)-1}
  \begin{scope}[
    help lines,
    every node/.style={inner sep=1pt,text=black}
    ]
    \foreach \coord in {1,...,\nticks} {
      \draw (\coord,\ltick,0) -- ++(0,-\ltick,0) -- ++(0,0,\ltick)
      node [pos=1,left] {\coord};
      \draw (\ltick,\coord,0) -- ++(-\ltick,0,0) -- ++(0,0,\ltick)
      node [pos=1,right] {\coord};
      \draw (\ltick,0,\coord) -- ++(-\ltick,0,0) -- ++(0,\ltick,0)
      node [at start,above right] {\coord};
    }
  \end{scope}
  %%% figure
  \filldraw [opacity=.33,red] (\xtriangle,0,0) -- (0,\ytriangle,0)
  -- (0,0,\ztriangle) -- cycle;
  \def\x2triangle{6}
  \def\y2triangle{5}
  \def\z2triangle{2}
  \def\ltick{.2}
  \begin{scope}[
    help lines,
    every node/.style={inner sep=1pt,text=black}
    ]
    \foreach \coord in {1,...,\nticks} {
      \draw (\coord,\ltick,0) -- ++(0,-\ltick,0) -- ++(0,0,\ltick)
      node [pos=1,left] {\coord};
      \draw (\ltick,\coord,0) -- ++(-\ltick,0,0) -- ++(0,0,\ltick)
      node [pos=1,right] {\coord};
      \draw (\ltick,0,\coord) -- ++(-\ltick,0,0) -- ++(0,\ltick,0)
      node [at start,above right] {\coord};
    }
  \end{scope}
  %%% figure
  \filldraw [opacity=.33,green] (\x2triangle,0,0) -- (0,\y2triangle,0)
  -- (0,0,\z2triangle) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```